# How does energy exist if it can't be created or destroyed?

Tags: energy

I saw this in a science book and it's been bugging me lately because how can energy exist if it can't have any creations?  How do eternal things exist if they have no beginning or ending, like energy?

Comment: The combination of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138972/50583) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19216/50583) question should answer that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to Stephen Hawking in 'A Breif History of Time', the total energy of the universe is zero. That's because there's negative energy associated with gravitational attraction. Add positive to an equal amount of negative, and you get zero.

So saying energy can't be created or destroyed just means you can't change the total energy of the universe, which is always at zero.