# Is it sufficient to define energy as "ability to do work"?

Tags: energy, work, definition

> **Energy** is the ability to do **work**. If an object possesses energy it possesses the ability to do work.

This is how energy is usually defined . This definition fits mechanical energy very well .

But I find it difficult to connect other forms of energy such as light energy , chemical energy, etc. to relate with work done .

I wonder how light or object with light has a capacity to do work?

Can someone clarify this ?
Is there any other definition for energy that fits every where?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138972/50583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can energy be useful when it is 'abstract'?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138972/)

Comment: This clarifies my doubts
Actually this question didn't came in suggestions so I thought this is not a duplicate.