# What kind of force is associated with the energy making up the rest mass of a particle?

Tags: forces, energy

Energy is mass ($E=mc^2$) and energy is defined as force times distance. So what kind of force is associated with the energy making up the rest mass of a particle?

Comment: *"Energy is defined as force times distance"* [citation needed] I think you confused energy and *work* there. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138972/50583 and their linked questions for more on the nature of energy.

Answer (score 0):

Energy is the ability to do work.
Work is force times displacement.

A particle with non-zero rest mass can be thought of  having an inertial resistance to movement through space because of the Higgs interactions. These interactions translates to rest mass.

Moreover, in case of atoms there are strong force interactions that give up to 98% of total mass.

In general, the Einstein's equation simply tells that energy can behave like mass. In fact, mass and energy are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).